# IntelliTest tests not working on async await methods

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, asynchronous, intellitest

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 and trying to use the feature they call IntelliTest.  IntelliTest seems to work fine when testing tradition synchronize methods.  However, most of my methods are async and return a Task, which require to be awaited.  When I create these IntelliTest unit tests, the results are always Result = "{Not yet computed}".  Does IntelliTest not support async methods, or I missing something?

Thanks

Comment: This is not supported presently.

Comment: That's really unfortunate given the current push from MS to use async await for all I/O.  I haven't been able to figure out if that is an enhancement on the intellitest roadmap, or if people like me using async await are just in the minority.